# Unity. Сцена стала долго грузиться

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет!
Проблема такая: 18 июня у меня сцена в мобильной игре грузилась за 1-2 секунды, а вот 30 июня сцена стала грузиться 5-6-7 секунд. Код почти не трогал, добавил 1 фоновую музыку, заменил спрайты и бекграунд. Я потом попробовал вернуть все старые спрайты, бекграунд и отключить код который я наклепал за это время - но это не помогло, сцена стала по прежнему грузиться 5-6-7 секунд вместо 1-2 секунд. В чем может быть проблема? Билдить он стал как-то не так что ли? На другом аппарате тоже проверил, там тоже грузится долго

я разобрался. проблема была в компоненте AudioSource и в методе в нем Play(), этот метод и компонент жрут очень много ресурсов. Но я не разобрался как снизить нагрузку, чтобы грузилось быстро

Comment: Как мы можем догадаться о ваших проблемах, если вы, по сути, ничего не показали? Ни кода, ничего

Comment: я разобрался. проблема была в компоненте AudioSource и в методе в нем Play(), этот метод и компонент жрут очень много ресурсов. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

я разобрался. проблема была в компоненте `AudioSource` и в методе в нем `Play()`, этот метод и компонент жрут очень много ресурсов.
Но я не разобрался как снизить нагрузку, чтобы грузилось быстро

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам ответ уже не нужен, но вдруг кто зайдёт в эту тему, а ответа нет. У меня похожая проблема была, и связана она действительно со звуками. В моём проекте музыка при окончании ставится на другую случайную из массива (Списка). Видимо, это всё весит очень много и поэтому долго грузится. В общем сделал меньше музыки - 4 (было около 10 клипов) и загрузка стала более менее быстрой.